# Using Python, I want to parse each file in one directory with format YY-MM-DD.CSV but ignore all others

Tags: python, regex, file, filter

I'm new to Python, so my example represents the mess one aggregates when all experiments so far have failed.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import glob
import os
import re
path = '/home2/SunnyDataBackup/currentGenerated/SBEAM/'
files = '[1][0-9]-[0-1][0-9]-[0-3][0-9].CSV$' #if I use '*.CSV', it works but doesn't filter the files
fullpath = os.path.join(path, files)
print fullpath
#fullpathC = re.compile(fullpath)

for filename in glob.glob(fullpath):
  print filename
```

Each file represents one day's solar panel generation but the directory also contains monthly summary CSV, with a `YYYY-MM.CSV` format. I want to tackle those files seprately. I'm aiming to go through the matching set of files in the directory, extract the date from the end of line 2 in the header, then many lines of time HH:MM and Power kWh with 3 decimal places. I plan to concatenate the date with each line's time into a timestamp and add the timestamp and the power to a MariaDB(MySQL) database. When each file has been parsed, I'll move it to a 'processed' subdirectory, so that any new files that are created can be processed once this program is converted to a cron.daily

The CSV file `15-04-27.CSV` looks like this:

```
sep=;
Version CSV|Tool SunnyBeam11|Linebreaks CR/LF|Delimiter semicolon|Decimalpoint point|Precision 3|Language en-UK|TZO=0|DST|2015.04.27

;SN: serial# removed
;SB model# removed
;serial# removed
Time;Power
HH:mm;kW
00:10;0.000
00:20;0.000
00:30;0.000
00:40;0.000
00:50;0.000
01:00;0.000
01:10;0.000
01:20;0.000
01:30;0.000
01:40;0.000
01:50;0.000
02:00;0.000
02:10;0.000
02:20;0.000
02:30;0.000
02:40;0.000
02:50;0.000
03:00;0.000
03:10;0.000
03:20;0.000
03:30;0.000
03:40;0.000
03:50;0.000
04:00;0.000
04:10;0.000
04:20;0.000
04:30;0.000
04:40;0.000
04:50;0.000
05:00;0.000
05:10;0.000
05:20;0.000
05:30;0.000
05:40;0.000
05:50;0.000
06:00;0.000
06:10;0.024
06:20;0.030
06:30;0.030
06:40;0.042
06:50;0.042
07:00;0.048
07:10;0.048
07:20;0.054
07:30;0.054
07:40;0.060
07:50;0.060
08:00;0.060
08:10;0.066
08:20;0.066
08:30;0.048
08:40;0.870
08:50;1.146
09:00;1.146
09:10;1.116
09:20;0.720
09:30;0.732
09:40;1.536
09:50;1.092
10:00;1.602
10:10;0.870
10:20;1.158
10:30;1.158
10:40;0.492
10:50;1.062
11:00;0.642
11:10;1.302
11:20;1.020
11:30;1.686
11:40;1.458
11:50;1.608
12:00;1.560
12:10;0.954
12:20;1.872
12:30;0.474
12:40;1.350
12:50;1.878
13:00;1.668
13:10;1.116
13:20;0.564
13:30;0.336
13:40;0.282
13:50;0.366
14:00;0.318
14:10;0.294
14:20;1.026
14:30;0.330
14:40;0.672
14:50;1.284
15:00;0.648
15:10;0.894
15:20;0.786
15:30;0.252
15:40;0.252
15:50;0.654
16:00;0.408
16:10;0.408
16:20;0.438
16:30;0.354
16:40;0.288
16:50;0.264
17:00;0.246
17:10;0.228
17:20;0.216
17:30;0.192
17:40;0.156
17:50;0.126
18:00;0.096
18:10;0.078
18:20;0.054
18:30;0.036
18:40;0.030
18:50;0.018
19:00;0.006
19:10;0.000
19:20;0.000
19:30;0.000
19:40;0.000
19:50;0.000
20:00;0.000
20:10;0.000
20:20;0.000
20:30;0.000
20:40;0.000
20:50;0.000
21:00;0.000
21:10;0.000
21:20;0.000
21:30;0.000
21:40;0.000
21:50;0.000
22:00;0.000
22:10;0.000
22:20;0.000
22:30;0.000
22:40;0.000
22:50;0.000
23:00;0.000
23:10;0.000
23:20;0.000
23:30;0.000
23:40;0.000
23:50;0.000
00:00;0.000


E-Today kWh;7.770
E-Total kWh;5534.780
```

Just to be clear what my question is: What's the best way to iterate through just the files I'm looking for (the ones with `YY-MM-DD.CSV` format)?

Thanks,

Greg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a function that returns whether a filename matches your YY-MM-DD.csv pattern or not.

```
from datetime import datetime

def is_dated_csv(filename):
    """
    Return True if filename matches format YY-MM-DD.csv, otherwise False.
    """
    date_format = '%y-%m-%d.csv'

    try:
        datetime.strptime(filename, date_format)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        # filename did not match pattern
        pass

    return False

# Tests
print is_dated_csv('15-01-01.CSV') # True
print is_dated_csv('99-12-31.csv') # True
print is_dated_csv('15-13-32.csv') # False
print is_dated_csv('15-02-30.csv') # False
```

The correct expected results are output for the tests. Note that filenames that do not make valid dates (e.g. the Feb. 30th test above) are correctly not matched. This would be more difficult to do with regular expressions. Note also that the .csv extension is case-insensitive.

The function is making use of the `datetime.datetime.strptime` method which is used to convert string representations of dates into `datetime` objects. It's useful in this case just to verify that that conversion is *possible*, meaning the string passed is a valid date string according to the specified format.

To use the function, you could do something like:

```
from os import listdir

path = 'path/to/your/csv/files/'

for filename in listdir(path):
    if is_dated_csv(filename):
        # Do something with the desired .csv file
        pass
```

Edit: `is_dated_csv` could be refactored to accept other formats, which would solve your issue of how also to detect other date patterns. See [the formatting chart in this section of the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

You can combine re and os.listdir:

```
import  re
import  os

r = re.compile(r"^\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}.csv$")
print([ f for f in os.listdir(".") if r.search(f)])
```

If it is actually `.CSV` change to `.CSV`, if it can be either use `re.I`:

```
 re.compile(r"^\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}.csv$", re.I)`
```

For the other pattern:

```
r2 = re.compile(r"^\d{4}-\d{2}.csv$")
print([ f for f in os.listdir(".") if r2.search(f)])
```